# EventStream api only return new transactions

Tags: javascript-sdk, event-stream

As mentioned in [Following payments using EventStream](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/tutorials/follow-received-payments.html#following-payments-using-2) I am able to receive the payment stream on the server side, now what if I want to return only new trisections from the time I start the stream? Is that possible?

```
var EventSource = require('eventsource');
var es = new EventSource('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GB7JFK56QXQ4DVJRNPDBXABNG3IVKIXWWJJRJICHRU22Z5R5PI65GAK3/payments');
es.onmessage = function(message) {
    var result = message.data ? JSON.parse(message.data) : message;
    console.log('New payment:');
    console.log(result);
};
es.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('An error occured!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add the parameter `cursor=now` to your request.

If you expect it may be in the future or the very recent past, you can run two streams (concurrently or in serial if you like), one with `cursor=now&order=desc` & consume events until you've found your expected payment or the timestamp is too early. And another with `cursor=now&order=asc` to check for future payments.

See the [documented arguments](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/payments-for-account.html#arguments).

Comment: But how can I make sure I am not missing the transaction as the confirmation time is seconds? My intention is to `start`/`stop` event stream on demand.

Comment: The api should give you access to the event id. When restarting, use the event id from the most recently seen event as the cursor.

Comment: My intention is not to keep it up and running along with the backend, but to start only when I am expecting a payment and stop as soon as I have the payment; possible?

Comment: Yes. If you expect it may be in the future _or_ the very recent past, you can run two streams (concurrently or in serial if you like), one with `cursor=now&order=desc` & consume events until you've found your expected payment or the timestamp is too early. And another with `cursor=now&order=asc` to check for future payments.

Comment: Great, consider adding that to original answer please.

Comment: Well, shoot they could accept a `timestamp` instead. Oh Jade....

Comment: Solved: I am getting old transaction even with `cursor=now&order=asc` using `JS SDK` it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the "Warning" [on the page](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/tutorials/follow-received-payments.html#following-payments-using-2), you may consider switching to [using the official JS SDK](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/#streaming-requests):

```
var lastCursor = "now"
var accountAddress = GB7JFK56QXQ4DVJRNPDBXABNG3IVKIXWWJJRJICHRU22Z5R5PI65GAK3

var es = server.transactions()
  .forAccount(accountAddress)
  .cursor(lastCursor)
  .stream({
      onmessage: txHandler
  })
```

`lastCursor="now"` gives you only new coming messages. You may try with using other values for `lastCursor`, other than zero (which will push out all the related info since the start of the chain).

Comment: But how can I make sure I am not missing the transaction as the confirmation time is seconds? My intention is to `start`/`stop` event stream on demand.

Comment: A cursor other than `now` uniquely identifies an event. Use the cursor value of the most recently seen event and you won't miss any.